# cmd zombie when i execute 'my.exe' in background from php (if there is some error in my.exe)

Tags: php, windows, process, background, cmd

I need to execute an .exe file from PHP in background.
I got a Windows 7 + XAMPP (PHP 5.2.9).

When i use this command:

`pclose(popen('start /b "title"  "'.$myEXE.'" -param1 -param2 > log.txt' , 'r'));`

if all goes right, there is no problem, the problem is if the .exe fails or has som problem.
When that happens, there is a cmd process that never dies and takes about 3-5 MB of RAM. If there are many processes... it may be a problem.

I don't know what i can do to avoid that.

Thanks!! ;)

Comment: If you have any way to figure out that their was an error, send a SIGKILL to the process in question ?

Comment: That's what I wanted to do. Because the log.txt (it's log_uniqueID.txt) is blocked by the zombie cmd and i can't delete it. So i will use `handle.exe` from [https://technet.microsoft.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) to kill cmd's.